# travis/coverity: automatically re-schedule a build after given time

Tags: travis-ci, coverity

I'm using `github`s integration of `travis-ci` with `coverity-scan` (the free versions of all these services) to test my FLOSS code.

The problem I'm facing is that when continuously working on the code, i'm hitting the *coverity* quota pretty soon.

Since I'm working on multiple projects simultaneously, it can therefore well be that I switch away from working on a given project before I'm allowed to submit a *coverity* again, thus potentially having flaws in the code for weeks although they would have been caught easily by *coverity*.

I would like to avoid this.

The first measure to prevent hitting the quota too frequently, is by using a dedicated branch (usually `coverity_scan`) which does not receive pushes as often as the master and/or feature branches.
However, this puts cognitive load on the user (me), which I also like to avoid.

Also, sometimes I still hit the quota (some of my projects as in the 100k-500k lines-of-code range, so they have a lower threshold than usual).

What I would like to have is being able to automatically re-trigger a *coverity-scan* once the quota has expired, if (and only if) the current build *did* hit the quota.

Is somthing like this possible with plain `travis-ci`/`coverity` features?

Or would I have to setup a separate hook, that monitors the coverity quota and travis-ci builds?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to run Coverity on every check-in.  It's just too slow.

You should configure your (coverity build) system to poll your repo for changes, but have them checked infrequently.  Something like a few times per day.

This will trigger the build when things change, but not on every change that is detected.

Comment: given that my "coverity build system" is travis-ci, how would i accomplish that?